# JavaScript jQuery-csv. How to trim() headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I have implemented [jQuery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/docs/api.md) library to parse data from CSV file. My CSV file looks like this:

```
name, description, client name, client address, client desc
Name 123, Descript 123, client name 123, client address 55, client desc 66
Name 456, Descript 456, client name 55, client address 55, client desc 66
```

I am using $.csv.toObjects(csv);

```
var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
```

Is it possible to trim() whitespace for headers?

Comment: Can you show us what the `data` variable looks like?

Comment: It's object type. Like data: {client: {name: "name 123", description: "Descript 123" ... The problem is behind this. I can't access these headers if there is any whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Based on `$.csv.toObjects(csv, options, callback)` in [doc](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Below is my solution for removing the whitespaces (using `callback`)

```
$.csv.toObjects(csvd, {}, function(err, data){
    $.each(data, function(index, row){
        $.each(row, function(key, value){
            var newKey = $.trim(key);
            if (typeof value === 'string'){
                data[index][newKey] = $.trim(value);
            }
            if (newKey !== key) {
                delete data[index][key];
            }
        });

    });
    processedData = data;
});
```